# Ionic2 code changes do not get reflected in the live app

Tags: ionic2

I have setup a new Ionic2 project using the Ionic CLI. I used ionic serve command to browse the website. Whenever I make changes to the html templates, I can see the linting and building process kick off, but the html or typescript changes are not reflected in the browser. I have tried several things such as clearing browser cache, using Chrome Incognito, and even killing the ionic session, and re-issuing the ionic serve command. Only after several hours, I see the code changes reflected in the browser. This is extremely frustrating...Please suggest a workaround. I am on Windows 10, Node version 6.9.4, ionic version 2.2.1

Package.json is:

```
{
  "name": "ionic-hello-world",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/forms": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.2.1",
    "@ionic/storage": "1.1.7",
    "angularfire2": "^2.0.0-beta.7",
    "firebase": "^3.6.9",
    "ionic-angular": "2.0.1",
    "ionic-native": "2.4.1",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.4.0",
    "zone.js": "0.6.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "^1.0.1",
    "@types/request": "0.0.39",
    "typescript": "2.0.9"
  },
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard"
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": [],
  "description": "webapp: An Ionic project"
}
```

Comment: can you add your package.json ?

Comment: I have added the package.json to my question.  Thanks

Comment: try setting app scripts version 1.1.3 https://github.com/driftyco/ionic2-app-base/blob/master/package.json#L31

Comment: @user2202866 I am having the same problem. Did you solve it?

Comment: did you find the way to solve it?